# Find the integral closure of a ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field, let $A=k[x,y]/(y^{2n}+y^{2n+2}-x^{2n+2})$ with fraction field $K$. Let $u=x^{n+1}/y^{n}, v=y/x$, then $x=uv^n, y=uv^{n+1}$. It's then easy to see that $1-u^2+u^2v^{2n+2}=0$. Let $A'=k[u,v]/(1-u^2+u^2v^{2n+2})$, which is easily seen to be smooth over $k$ (hence normal) and also has fraction field $K$.

Since $u^2=y^2+1$, $u$ is integral over $A$. I want to show that $A'$ is the integral closure of $A$ in $K$, so only need to show that $v$ is integral over $A$. I can't see why.

Other way to find the integral closure of $A$ in $K$ is also fine.

You may assume $k=\mathbb{C}$ if convenient.

Comment: Are you sure $v$ is integral over $A$? I may have missed something, but for example in the case $n=0$ we have $1+y^2-x^2=0$ and $v^2=1-1/x^2$. It seems to me that if $v$ is integral so is $1/x$?

Comment: I'm not very sure, it's claimed that A' is the normalisation of A (in its fraction field K) in a course notes on AG, but may have typo. I tried hard and spent quite some time to confirm it but failed. One way may be to show 1/u is integral...It's still interesting to find the normalisation even though that's wrong.

Comment: OK, let's assume characteristic not 2.